# How to Retrieve HTML Control Type using FormCollection in ASP.NET MVC Controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have View where I am creating hidden html controls (dynamically) and then  filling the values of hidden controls on certain conditions using JQuery and then later posting back to server Http Post.

here is the sample:

```
<input id="1" name="1" type="hidden" value="" />
<tr>
  <td>1</td>
  <td>مدى تحقيق البرنامج لتوقعاتك</td>
  <td><input class="radio" name="11" onclick=" $(&#39;#1&#39;).val(&#39;1&#39;);" type="radio" value="1" /></td>
  <td><input class="radio" name="11" onclick=" $(&#39;#1&#39;).val(&#39;2&#39;);" type="radio" value="2" /></td>
  <td><input class="radio" name="11" onclick=" $(&#39;#1&#39;).val(&#39;3&#39;);" type="radio" value="3" /></td>
  <td><input class="radio" name="11" onclick=" $(&#39;#1&#39;).val(&#39;4&#39;);" type="radio" value="4" /></td>
  <td><input class="radio" name="11" onclick=" $(&#39;#1&#39;).val(&#39;5&#39;);" type="radio" value="5" /></td>
</tr>
<input id="2" name="2" type="hidden" value="" />
<tr>
  <td>2</td>
  <td>مدى ملائمة المادة العلمية</td>
  <td><input class="radio" name="12" onclick=" $(&#39;#2&#39;).val(&#39;1&#39;);" type="radio" value="1" /></td>
  <td><input class="radio" name="12" onclick=" $(&#39;#2&#39;).val(&#39;2&#39;);" type="radio" value="2" /></td>
  <td><input class="radio" name="12" onclick=" $(&#39;#2&#39;).val(&#39;3&#39;);" type="radio" value="3" /></td>
  <td><input class="radio" name="12" onclick=" $(&#39;#2&#39;).val(&#39;4&#39;);" type="radio" value="4" /></td>
  <td><input class="radio" name="12" onclick=" $(&#39;#2&#39;).val(&#39;5&#39;);" type="radio" value="5" /></td>
```

In ASP.NET Web Forms  we can easily check the html control type in the code behind event, Now my question is how to filter only HTML hidden controls in the Action Method in the Controller. How I can retrieve the only hidden controls form key/value in my Action Method using Form Collection?? I hope you understand my question very well.

Comment: This information is not retained upon form submission; all you get are key-value pairs.

Comment: You cant - forms only post back the name/value pairs of its successful form controls

Comment: Is there is any other way around to solve this problem? I just want to retrieve values which Jquery inserted in the hidden controls. I don't really know the name of the control as it will be generated dynamically.

Comment: What are you trying to do here? Why in the world are you manually generating your html and using `FormCollection` instead of doing this correctly and binding to a model and posting back to the model.

Comment: I am asking question to the user and giving him opportunity to use RADIO buttons to answer experience level (Excellent, Good, Fair, Bad )etc.  It is simply  more like a survey form.   I don't have particular model  for this View I already generating them using a View Model filling all my questions in the I enumerable Collection.

Comment: I agress wuth stephen.  you need to stop thinking about the issue in terms of webforms terminology/technology and think about the problem using pure html/http.  radio buttons are mutually exclusive, there's no reason to have to copy the value into a hidden field to get is back to the server.  the posted value will be the name of the html element and the value of that element.